# How and when should one add "[sic]" to a quotation in a SE answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, blockquote

In *[What should I do about answers that are obviously intended to be accepted, but actually aren't? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354446/what-should-i-do-about-answers-that-are-obviously-intended-to-be-accepted-but-a)*, I directly quoted someone's comment:

> @sanjay I see your new to stack exchange. If your happy with the answer then please 'accept' the answer my selecting the tick by it. This helps show other users if a question has been answered or not. – StartPlayer Apr 25 at 10:52

The "*your*"s bothered me, and I considered either:

- Changing them to "*[you're]*".
- Changing them to "*your [sic]*".

But decided that since it was obviously a cut'n'paste of an entire comment, there was an implicit "sic" on the whole quotation.

Later, someone with 6 times my reputation *did* make the change (with a helpful link to wikihow):

> @sanjay I see your [[sic][2]] new to stack exchange. If your [sic] happy with the answer then please 'accept' the answer my selecting the tick by it. This helps show other users if a question has been answered or not. – StartPlayer Apr 25 at 10:52

Being somewhat anal retentive, I'm happy with that change, but I still wonder if it's necessary, or even appropriate, for a direct copy of a comment.  (I've seen more than a few "-ize" and "-ise" words that were followed by what I'd consider unnecessary and distracting "sic"s.)

When should and should not one use "sic", and is that form, with the link, documented anywhere as being the way to do it within the SE sites?

Comment: I would just take initiative and add it whenever I am not comfortable with what I am quoting. Etiquette/procedure does not necessarily have to micro-manage every single word we write...

Comment: Comments can't be edited after a few minutes and [the help encourages us to treat them like "temporary "Post-It" notes "](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), so I would expect most people to overlook mistakes that don't make the meaning unclear. If you're directly quoting someone and there's no confusion about their meaning, it seems pedantic in an ugly way to highlight the mistakes. If you can't stand looking at the mistake, it would be better to paraphrase and link to the comments (click on a comment's timestamp for a direct link to it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to use *sic*, in particular because you don’t want to look like you’re rubbing someone’s mistakes in their face or trying to act superior. As a reader I also find it distracting, even more so than the errors themselves.

There are much better options:

- Paraphrase! “A commenter asked for their answer to be accepted if it solved the problem and the OP said they did but the answer wasn’t accepted.” It both avoids the issue of *sic*/typos entirely and makes the post easier to read (as what you have is longer and fails to convey that the first comment is from the person who answered the question). Anyone who needs additional information can click on the link to the comments.
- Find a different example that doesn’t have issues.
- Quote the entire thing as is, without adding *sic* to any of the four mistakes (yes, there were other mistakes: lowercase “Stack Exchange” and “my” instead of “by”). If you thought it was likely for someone to accidentally edit thinking these were *your* mistakes, then you could leave something that would only be visible when editing, such as `<sic>` (as anything looking like a unsupported HTML tag is stripped).
- Quote around the issues. (For what you’re quoting I don’t see a good way to do this though and would instead paraphrase.) This also can be a more elegant solution than using brackets, such as when a quoted pronoun is unclear out of context.

Also, remember that when quoting a post, your best solution is to fix errors in the original, then quote that. This may mean that you have to edit other posts that reproduce the error, but that’s fine. (Same goes for when editing an OP’s comment into their post: I usually end up cutting up and heavily modifying the comment so that it has no errors and fits better.)

Across all my posts on both SE sites dedicated to the English language (where many of these posts quote sources that don’t use standard English), I have used *sic* [only once](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/545637/191178) (outside of a handful posts talking about *sic* itself), referring to a misspelled book title from the 1500s, where the inclusion of *sic* was based on it appearing in [another source](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A10439.0001.001?view=toc).

Answer (score 10):

*[sic]* means *exactly so* or *verbatim* and usually is used to point out an authors inability of correct writing.
It's often enough abused just to exhibit a person, and that's a thing going ad hominem and violates the code of conduct.

So unless in a linguistic or otherwise technical context you shouldn't use it.

Comment: That's why I refrained from using it.  I *would* use it only if I thought it likely that people would have reason to think that it was *my* misspelling.

Comment: @RayButterworth You should simply show the _grandezza_ that you've understood the intended meaning well, and just correct it in the cite.

Answer (score 6):

I would say practically never. It's noise, and in many cases it is either not important or it is clear it is a quote and it adds no real information.

It may be useful quoting from an external source if the spelling mistakes carry some meaning and/or you want to let people know not to fix it.

In your particular context - you may be better off paraphrasing.

So you would include '[sic]' if and only if it acts to provide information useful to the reader in some way.

Answer (score 2):

What is this, a Strunk and White lesson?

I'm going to make the argument that we're not here to teach the appropriate usage of such quotation markers; there is a [wealth of information](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/figuring-out-the-trick-behind-sic/) already out there on the web that one should lean on instead of a whole bunch of us who just use the network.

Comment: I know *how* to use "sic".  I was asking about policy and procedure within the StackExchange sites.  I've updated the question to make this more obvious.

Comment: Given that this is an English construct (mostly used with references), I believe the policy of "English is the official language" is sufficient here.  If you feel the need to quote someone in this fashion then use it since it's part of English.  Otherwise I don't think there's any policy policing readily at hand for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the original question, and from the responses I can conclude that:

- No, SE has no documentation for when "sic" is appropiate to use, nor how it should be used.
- The person that added "sic" and the wikihow link to the referenced question used a personal formula.

In addition, I've learned that:

- Adding "sic" should be avoided (which was what I had done in this case), unless it actually affects the understanding of the text.
- "sic" can be avoided by using paraphrasing or indirect quotations.
- The whole issue can be eliminated by correcting the text at the source, and then quoting the already corrected version.

I suspect that this is useful advice for other people to know too.

Ignoring the one answer that missed the point of the question, the answers have so far received 21 upvotes, and the question 7 upvotes, and both comments on the question offered useful advice.

So both the question and the answers must have some merit.

---

The one thing I don't understand is the 2 votes to close and the 13 downvotes against the question.

- Was the question "*unclear*"?   (It generated 3 useful answers.)
- Did it "*lack research*"?  (The lack of references is because I couldn't find any, and that's because they don't exist.)
- Is is "*not useful*"?  (Now anyone that wonders whether adding "sic" is a good idea can find this question and learn that it isn't.)

Obviously it's not simply one unreasonable person picking on this, and 13 is too big for a conspiracy against me.  The negative responses must be independently inspired. But what is the cause of those 13 downvotes?

It would be very helpful to my understanding if some of those people could add a comment here indicating *why* they voted as they did.

(And yes, I know the votes don't count for anything; I'm sincerely interested in knowing why so many people decided to down-vote it.)